# CakePHP: how to structure find() result data when querying a table with 3 foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp

I have a table that links 3 other tables in such a way:

```
| id                    | int(11)  |
| asociado_id           | int(11)  |
| almacen_transporte_id | int(11)  |
| operacion_venta_id    | int(11)  |
| sacos_asignados       | int(11)  |
```

sort of a tri-dimensional table. `asociado_id`, `almacen_transporte_id` and `operacion_venta_id` are all foreign keys.
What I need to do is query this 3D table to extract 2D arrays assiging a value to one of the 3 foreign keys like:

SELECT * FROM table where asociado_id=m;

SELECT * FROM table where almacen_transporte_id = n;

SELECT * FROM table where operacion_venta_id = p;

The problem is that when I use

```
$this->OperacionAsociadoCuenta->find(
'all',
array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'operacion_venta_id' => $p
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Asociado',
        'AlmacenTransporte
   )
)
```

the array returned isn't structured in a hierachical way. I get something like:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'OperacionAsociadoCuenta' => array(
            'id' => '573',
            'asociado_id' => '75',
            'almacen_transporte_id' => '12',
            'operacion_venta_id' => '64',
            'sacos_asignados' => '45'
        ),
        'AlmacenTransporte' => array(
            'id' => '12',
        ),
        'Asociado' => array(
            'id' => '75',
            'nombre' => 'Cafés Baqué, S.L.U.'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'OperacionAsociadoCuenta' => array(
            'id' => '574',
            'asociado_id' => '81',
            'almacen_transporte_id' => '12',
            'operacion_venta_id' => '64',
            'sacos_asignados' => '5'
        ),
        'AlmacenTransporte' => array(
            'id' => '12',
        ),
        'Asociado' => array(
            'id' => '81',
            'nombre' => 'Café Dromedario, S.A.'
        )
     ),
     (int) 2 => array(
        'OperacionAsociadoCuenta' => array(
            'id' => '577',
            'asociado_id' => '81',
            'almacen_transporte_id' => '54',
            'operacion_venta_id' => '64',
            'sacos_asignados' => '5'
         ),
         'AlmacenTransporte' => array(
            'id' => '54',
         ),
         'Asociado' => array(
            'id' => '81',
            'nombre' => 'Café Dromedario, S.A.'
          )
      )
```

And what I really need is:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'AlmacenTransporte' => array(
            'id' => '12',
        ),
        array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'Asociado' => array(
                    'id' => '75',
                    'nombre' => 'Cafés Baqué, S.L.U.'
                 )
                 'sacos_asignados' => '45'
             ),
             (int) 1 => array(
                 'Asociado' => array(
                     'id' => '81',
                     'nombre' => 'Café Dromedario, S.A.'
                 ),
                 'sacos_asignados' => '5'
             )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'AlmacenTransporte' => array(
            'id' => '54'
        ),
        array(
             (int) 0 => array(
                 'Asociado' => array(
                     'id' => '81',
                     'nombre' => 'Café Dromedario, S.A.'
                 ),
                 'sacos_asignados' => '5'
             )
        )
    )
)
```

Is there a way I can achieve this tuning the params I pass to find() ?
Should I use some Hash::combine() instead ?

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Can you provide the relationship between these 3 tables.

Comment: `OperacionVenta` hasMany `OperacionAsociadoCuenta`,  

`AlmacenTransporte` hasMany `OperacionAsociadoCuenta`,  

`Asociado` hasMany `OperacionAsociadoCuenta`